# Read a text file into a hash map with words as keys

Tags: java

I have a textfile and I am trying to read it into a hashmap. My problem is that I am trying to use the words as keys. I have searched around and cannot find a solution.

So basically if I have a textfile `"text.txt"` that contains this: `"This is a sentence."` I want to make a hashmap of the words where the first key is `"This"` and the value is `{"is", "a", "sentence."}`. And then the next key is `"is"` with values `{"a", "sentence."}`, and so on until every word is used as a key.

Comment: What happens when you encounter the second "This" in the text file?  Also, you should remove all punctuation and make all the words lower-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
String input = "This is a sentence.";
String[] split = input.split(" ");
Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>(split.length - 1);
for (int i = 0; i < split.length - 1; i++) {
    int remainderLength = split.length - 1 - i;
    String[] remainders = new String[remainderLength];
    System.arraycopy(split, i + 1, remainders, 0, remainderLength);
    map.put(split[i], remainders);
}
```

Split the string on spaces, iterate over until the last but one, and put the entries in the `HashMap`.

If you want the last word to map to an empty array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    int remainderLength = split.length - 1 - i;
    String[] remainders = new String[remainderLength];
    if (remainderLength > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(split, i + 1, remainders, 0, remainderLength);
    }
    map.put(split[i], remainders);
}
```

Comment: Based on the question, the last word should be a key as well, presumably mapping to an empty array.

Comment: For smaller memory footprint when text file is large, change the `String[] split = ...` to `List<String> split = Arrays.asList(...)` and use `subList()`. This will not copy the array.

Comment: This answer does not address the problems caused by the same word appearing more than once (the map will contain only the last instance).